# qt.bluetooth.bluez: services data does not fit into advertising data packet

Tags: qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to understand why the error raises.
This my code:

```
const QBluetoothUuid UUID_ADV = QBluetoothUuid(QString("{cb27cfad-zzzz-yyyy-xxxx-4e589e63ede3}"));

QLowEnergyAdvertisingData advertisingData;
advertisingData.setDiscoverability(QLowEnergyAdvertisingData::DiscoverabilityGeneral);
advertisingData.setIncludePowerLevel(false);
advertisingData.setLocalName("0123456789");
advertisingData.setServices(QList<QBluetoothUuid>() << UUID_ADV);

leController->startAdvertising(QLowEnergyAdvertisingParameters(), advertisingData, QLowEnergyAdvertisingData());
```

So I want to advertise a local name of 10 chars length and an UUID of 128-bit (16 byte).
As far as I know each advertising information is composed of 1-byte type and a variable-length payload. In my case I should have:

```
0x09 + 10 byte
0x07 + 16 byte
```

In total there are 28 byte, well below the boundary of 31-bytes.
I'm surely missing something!